# Remove all paragraphs based on order (after the 2rd, 3th or 4th...)

Tags: php, preg-replace, paragraph

I got this

```
$description =  '<p>text1</p><p>text2</p><p>text3</p><p>text4</p><p>textn</p>'
```

I want to remove only what comes after `<p>text3</p>`

My result would be:

```
$description = '<p>text1</p><p>text2</p><p>text3</p>'
```

My guess is that we need to use `preg_replace` with some regex but I can't manage to write a working one.

Comment: It's almost 2013. Use an XML parser.

Comment: Never use regex to parse XML. You might cause a mental meltdown of some random developer somewhere in the future ... or in the past.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/499214

Comment: regex is probably not the best tool for this job but I would think if your markup is uniform then a regex could work.  You haven't given us the structure of the document so it's hard to come up with a regex.  I don't know preg syntax off the top of my head but something like `((<p>[^<]*</p>){3}).*` as a group and then replace with `\1`

Comment: This is the tool for you: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: @Jan Dvorak: sometimes pragmatism > principle. Here's my aircode version: `$cleanDescription = preg_replace('/((<p>[^<]*</p>){3}).*/i','$1', $description);`  Obviously Wistar there are a number of problems with using regex but it might be okay for your use-case.    Just depends.  Best thing would be to encapsulate the functionality in a function and then you can change the implementation as needed.

Comment: @User This will fail horribly (do nothing at all) if the `p` tags are unclosed (which is valid HTML) or contain other tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could...

```
function str_occurance($needle, $haystack, $occurance) { 
$occurance += 2;
$arr = explode($needle, $haystack, $occurance);
unset($arr[0]);
$arr = array_values($arr);
$key = count($arr) - 1;
unset($arr[$key]);
$str = $needle . implode($needle, $arr);
return $str; 
}
```

Not the prettiest, but it works.

Edit: To use:

```
$description =  '<p>text1</p><p>text2</p><p>text3</p><p>text4</p><p>textn</p>';
$split = '<p>';
$return = 3;
$new = str_occurance($needle, $description, $return);
echo $new; // returns <p>text1</p><p>text2</p><p>text3</p>
```